# How to define chinese characters in php?

Tags: php, xml, unicode

I have given a php file to define a few chinese characters in the file
with define function.

eg
define('one', 'e');

I am to replace e with a chinese character.
Do I just cut and paste chinese character over it or
do I have to use some hex value like 𺧞 
Is there a simpler way to do this ?

How do I do that ?
How do I save this file in my editor (in what format, with or without BOM) ?
I use TextWrangler or notepad++

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.
Sincerely

Comment: you have asked nine questions so far and received more than a dozen answers. You are encouraged to accept those answers most helpful and/or solving your question by ticking the green checkmark icon next to them. This shows your appeciation and will also make people more willing to help on any further questions you have. If none of the answers to a question satisfy your question, update the question with additional details for people to better understand what you are looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can just type that in, e.g.

```
define('HELLO', '你好');
```

but you have to be aware that not all functions are multibyte aware, e.g.

```
echo strlen('你好'); // 6
echo mb_strlen('你好'); // 2
```

Comment: Note that you need to save your PHP file in the correct encoding for this to work (probably preferably UTF-8), and the page's output encoding needs to match.